# How to disable the background while displaying the toast message?

Tags: android

I want to create a toast message which when shows, the background view should disable for a particular period of time. Normally while displaying the toast we can handle the buttons or views in the background.

Comment: I would not suggest you to do so. As toast message is native Android metaphor; in such case it is advisable to use dialog, using custom dialog you should can easily set the visibility of other part of Activity.

Answer (score 1):

You can change you background view's visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE to accomplish it ...

Here is the sample program  how to do it...

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Visibility1.html

---

Do you want to do like that ?

[image]

you might want to apply the theme programmatically to the activity

Create a res/values/styles.xml file and add this to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Dim" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

And apply the theme to your activity.

To apply it programmatically,

setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dim);

or use this tutorial to learn how to do it

http://www.anddev.org/applying_a_theme_to_your_application-t817.html

Comment: Actually i don't want to invisible/gone the view. Just want to disable it same as the behavior of using Alert box

Answer (score 0):

i dont think toast has that option,instead what i would suggest is use customized dialog box look alike toast.
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example

you can avoid buttons in the example.

Later have a simple thread running for a short time and then dismiss the dialog.